# CLS (ClearScreen) command not working when .bat file is run from task scheduler

Tags: command, windows-task-scheduler, cls

I am trying to build a batch file (Using MS Notepad) to accomplish the following:

1. Write a message to the console ("Running Task X - Do not interrupt")
2. Run some commands with the output being written to a log file
3. Pause
4. CLEAR THE SCREEN (CLS)
5. Write a different message to the console ("Running Task Y - Do not interrupt")
6. Run some more commands with the output being written to the log file
7. Pause until the screen is manually cleared

When I run my test file directly by double-clicking it, the Clear Screen command works as expected.
(of course, the output of steps 2 and 6 will also show on the screen rather than being written to a log file)

When I run the file from the task scheduler, The CLS is ignored and BOTH messages will show on the screen
(In this case, the output of steps 2 and 6 is properly directed to a log file)

How can I properly clear the screen when running the file from Task Scheduler?

My batch test file:

```
@Echo OFF

mode con: cols=85 lines=40

echo ===  This machine is currently performing task "X"   Please do NOT interrupt   === >con

Dir PlaceHolder*

Pause >con

@CLS

echo ===  This machine is currently performing task "Y"   Please do NOT interrupt   === >con

Dir PlaceHolder2*

Pause >con

@Exit
```

Comment: How do you see the messages being displayed when you run the script via the task scheduler? Where do you see it? Isn't it run in a non-visible shell?

Comment: @progman: The Task scheduler routes the output to a log file (this is specified when scheduling the task) The batch file itself routes SOME text to the screen using the >con command. Thus the screen will initially show "===  This machine is currently performing task "X"   ===". Once the DIR command has completed, the PAUSE command will issue a prompt: :"Press any key to continue . . ." Once ENTER is pressed,  a second line will be added: "===  This machine is currently performing task "Y"   Please do NOT interrupt   ===".  Output from both DIR commands goes to the log file.

Comment: (In the question I posted, I am showing the DIR command to simplify things. In the "real" batch file, more complex commands are executed. Those commands can take up to a couple of hours to complete. This is the reason for displaying the "Do not interrupt" message)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these additional information, they should be part of the question, not a comment.

Comment: Apparently I am not the only one who encountered this problem. User dbenham posted (https://superuser.com/questions/1347898/force-output-to-console-in-a-batch-script-with-output-redirected-to-a-file) "...not all functionality works properly when directed to con. For example, cls does not properly clear the screen."

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if you only use "@CLS" (as I did), the Clearscreen command gets directed to the LOG rather than to the screen. Since the log CANNOT be cleared, the batch file prepends the next line of output with an upwards arrow and calls it a day.
You will need to ensure you explicitly route the Clearscreen command to the console/screen (@CLS >con) in which case it will work as expected.